# flexbox issue - display flex doesn't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need help with this flexbox issue.
Spans doesn't shows when i use flexbox, they do not have width: 50px anymore.

```
<div class="mobile-nav-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>


    .mobile-nav-toggle{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: pink;
        margin-right: 20px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        span,
        span::before,
        span::after{
            content: "";
            display: block;
            height: 2px;
            background: #333;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Missing closing tag. 2 lines commented out. These are the absolute basics of CSS, please read about it a little before copying the code from somewhere else.

Comment: There is closing tag . I didn't copy it properly.

Comment: I commented them out on purpose to see the spans. Because if I use flexbox on parent container they don't shows.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you got 1 missing closing curly bracket in your CSS.

```
.mobile-nav-toggle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    span,
    span::before,
    span::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        background: #333;}
    }
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/greyk50/md027dr9/)
I inspect with developer tools, it shows the span has 50px width.